# How to call an Object Method in Java

Tags: java, object

I've looked all over the internet, but I can't figure out what I'm doing wrong. I'm trying my hand at using private variables from another class using get/set methods. Something's going wrong, but I can't figure it out.

```
public class Character
{
   private int atk = 0;
   private int def = 0;
   private int spd = 0;

   public void setStat(String stat, int n)
   {
      stat = stat.toLowerCase();

      if(stat.equals("def") || stat.equals("defence") || stat.equals("defense"))
      {
         def = n;
      }
      if(stat.equals("atk") || stat.equals("attack"))
      {
         atk = n;
      }
      if(stat.equals("spd") || stat.equals("speed"))
      {
         spd = n;
      }
   }

   public int getStat(String stat)
   {
       stat = stat.toLowerCase();
       int n = -1;
       if(stat.equals("def") || stat.equals("defence") || stat.equals("defense"))
       {
          n = def;
       }
       if(stat.equals("atk") || stat.equals("attack"))
       {
          n = atk;
       }
       if(stat.equals("spd") || stat.equals("speed"))
       {
          n = spd;
       }
       return n;
   }
   public Character(int a, int d, int c)
   {
      atk = a;
      def = d;
      spd = c;
   }
}
```

This is my first class, `Character` which will be used as the template for the object, complete with get/set methods.

```
public class newCharacters
{
   Character person1 = new Character(2, 4, 3);
   person1.getStat("atk");
}
```

This is my second class, which constructs a character object and then tries to get a variable. Problem is, whenever I compile, it says that the object method needs an identifier. Exact quote: `<identifier> expected`

I can't figure out what it means, or what I'm doing wrong? I made get/set methods for each class, created the object in both classes, even constructed and called the object method within the `Character` class. Same problem every time. Can someone help?

Comment: code in `newCHaracters` should be in method, no just inside of class

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
public class newCharacters
{
   Character person1 = new Character(2, 4, 3);
   person1.getStat("atk");
}
```

This should not be in a class. This does not mean anything. A class can have bunch of instance variables and methods.

Please study the basics well ;)

Put it in a main method inside the `Character` class

```
public static void main(String [] args) {
   Character person1 = new Character(2, 4, 3);
   person1.getStat("atk");
}
```

Comment: Oh... right. *facepalms* yeah, thanks. I don't know how I forgot something so simple.

Answer (score 0):

```
public class NewCharacters
{

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Character person1 = new Character(2, 4, 3);
        person1.getStat("atk");
    }
}
```

A program starts a main method like above.
Inside a class, at the top level only fields and methods may be declared (and constructors and initializer blocks, and other classes).